# How many Frames decoder stores in his memory-buffer

Tags: decoder, ijkplayer

Just want to know how long decoder will buffer frames until next I frame comes?

**If we consider a GOP I1P2P3P4I2P5P6...
Then, the decoder will buffer up to I1 to P4?**

If suppose I require frame P4 again after decoding P6 then what decoder will do?

Decoder flash the buffer and start decoding from I1 until P4 reaches?

Comment: What video file format are you taking about ? For exemple, I saw mp4 files with IPB frames that had about fifteen reference frames.